# Crontab not working */10: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have first tried to execute a php file.

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php/ /path/to/file/file.php
```

I got: -bash: */10: no such file or directory

Then I tried to make it as simple as possible with a curl command. The curl command is working perfectly. But if I try to make a crontab task:

```
*/10 * * * * curl "https://test.php"
```

it doesnt work and I get: */10: No such file or directory.

I've also tried

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/curl/ https://test.php
```

I don't understand that.

Comment: Why is bash trying to execute a crontab file?

Answer (score 0):

To parse and execute php, you will need to use the -f flaf and you also don't need a / after the path to the php bin file and so:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/file/file.php
```

Comment: Also not working
-bash: */10: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the path to the php file exist?

Comment: Yes, I can open it with vi.
I mean the error is also if I make a curl...
That doent make sense

Comment: Did you use crontab -e to make the entry?

Comment: The I get a "?" as return value

Comment: Make sure you are using crontab -e to make the entry. It will then tell you if there are any syntax errors.

Comment: But as I said I get a "?". Dont know what that should mean